# Text-indent bug in safari, or expected behavior?

Tags: css, safari

I've put a little demo of the problem I'm trying to debug here: http://jsfiddle.net/bvDBb/7/.

The text-indent works as expected (or at least the way I expect it to) in Chrome, Firefox and Opera - it indents the first line of the text and then performs the wrapping again to keep the padding correct.

However, when viewed in Safari (5.1.7 on OS X 10.7.4) instead of wrapping the text, it creates a horizontal scrollbar and just moves the first line to the right - and with a large enough indentation, part of the line gets hidden and you have to scroll to see it.

Is that a bug in Safari, or am I just lucky that the rest of the browsers support it?

EDIT:

As Keith's idea of adding a `<p></p>` around the text fixes the layout (at least on Safari, haven't tried FF on Win), the question remains more like: what is the correct behavior and why?

Answer (score 0):

try adding   `overflow-x:hidden;` under   `overflow-y:auto;` in `.content`

Comment: Well, my point is not just to avoid the horizontal scroll bar, but to get it work correctly as a whole. With the `overflow: hidden;` I even lose the rest of the first line.

Comment: if you wrap your lorem text in `<p></p>` tags it should solve that

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the actual CSS property `text-indent` for a text-indent like this. Such as:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <div class="content" style="text-indent: 100px;">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="some image" />
    <p class="indent-me">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta mattis lectus, in fringilla magna posuere vitae.</p>
  </div>
</div>​

p.indent-me {
  text-indent:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'em' instead of 'px'

```
text-indent:30em;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it works perfect both on desktop and mobile Safari.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
text-indent: 30px;
}
```